# using sscanf() read from command line

Tags: c, argv, scanf

I want to get two values in the command line like this : ./part4 -f 50.0 
I need to get the character as well as the float number.
The character can only be 'f' or 'c'.
So I write this:

```
if ( sscanf(argv[1], "-%[cf]",&flag) !=1 )
{
    printf("invalid input flag!\n");
}
else printf("flag=%c\n",flag);

if ( sscanf(argv[2], "%f", &temp) !=1 )
{
    printf("invalid input temperature!\n");
}
else printf("temp=%f\n",temp);
```

I run some test:

```
  ./part4 -f 50.0
  flag=f
  invalid input temperature!

  ./part4 -d 50.0
  invalid input flag!
  temp=50.000000
```

I think there is something wrong with my first sscanf(), but I could not figure it out.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour in the 2 cases you have shown? Have you considered using `argp_parse` instead of using sscanf?

Comment: @jayant I was asked to use the sscanf() to get the character as well as the  float number from the command line. 'c' or 'f' indicates what kind of temperature it is, then i need to make a conversion between Fahrenheit and Celsius.

Comment: So what should happens when you enter `-d`

Comment: @jayant./part4 -d
invalid input flag!
make: *** [test4] Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: Why did @user3121023 delete his answer? Seems like a good one...